# ARToolKit OSG Model Loading Failure

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, artoolkit, postmortem-debugging

I'm trying to build ARToolKit from the SDK from [artoolkit.org](http://artoolkit.org), however I am running into some issues. The application, simpleOSG, which is an included example application, is building from source. However, when it is run, it crashes. When debugged, it breaks at:

```
#ifndef DEBUG_AROSG_MODELLOADING
        osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> model = NULL;
        // Ask OSG to load the model.
        // Check if object file refers to an image.
        std::stromg ext = osgDB::getLowerCaseFileExtension(modelFilePath);
```

And gives the following output:

```
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\simpleOSGd.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\ARvideod.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\ARosgd.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfplat.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfreadwrite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\pthreadVC2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\DSVLd.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\glut32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\osg100-osg.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\osg100-osgFX.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\osg100-osgGA.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\osg100-osgViewer.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\osg100-osgUtil.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\quartz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\ot20-OpenThreads.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\osg100-osgDB.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\osg100-osgText.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ARToolKit5\bin\zlib1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksuser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfperfhelper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RTWorkQ.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\tv_w32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.14393.447_none_5507ded2cb4f7f4c\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devenum.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msdmo.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfksproxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atl.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfsensorgroup.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksproxy.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\policymanager.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vidcap.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Kswdmcap.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfc42.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dpapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qedit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.14393.953_none_baad48403594ab3f\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\LVUI2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\LVUI2RC.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.14393.953_none_89c2555adb023171\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\actxprxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\edputil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pcacli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sfc_os.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devrtl.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0311199.inf_amd64_71ef621a77f87d8c\atiglpxx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0311199.inf_amd64_71ef621a77f87d8c\atioglxx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxva2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0311199.inf_amd64_71ef621a77f87d8c\atigktxx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiadlxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'simpleOSGd.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x1ca4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x6B754BD6 (osg100-osgDB.dll) in simpleOSGd.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCD315FC3.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Jack

Windows 10, VS 2013, ARToolKit 5.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by switching the build settings from debug to release in VS.